# django_migrations outputs ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword?

Tags: python, django, oracle, pycharm, migration

When I try to run the python manage.py migrate command I get the following error

```
raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
```

and

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword)
```

**Note:**

I can read and write to an oracle database and using **PYCharm IDE**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using old Oracle version <12.1. Oracle supports virtual generated columns only since 12.1 (`generate always`)
Upgrade it to Oracle 19, or at least to 12.2 (premium support ends in 4 days - 31th of March)

Comment: Thanks. But i will not be able to upgrade oracle. Is there a different option?

Comment: only create such tables with sequences manually with row-level triggers which will update primary keys from those sequences. I would suggest to install oracle 19, run migration and then use export-import with manual changes